# Git push command is not reflecting changes on Github Repo

Tags: git, github, version-control, push

I am pushing my files to my remote repo using the push command. However, no addition of changes is displaying in Github repo. Commits are showing but no code or text file is updated on Github while using push.
[image: I typed all the commands]

[image: index.html is empty on github]

I tried,
`git push origin master:master`
nothing is working for display of changes live on github repo

Comment: In my opinion the best tool to visualize git history is `gitk --all`. It should clearly show the relation between `master` and `origin/master` and from the question text I am guessing that the problem is that changes are not commit on the `master` branch. Gitk will clearly show that to.

Answer (score 1):

The screenshot with VS Code window shows `index.html` marked as modified since opening. It looks like you have NOT saved the file before committing and pushing.

After you save, commit and push the changes should appear in your GitHub repo.